# Problems validating credit card using Paypals PayFlow API

Tags: php, paypal

I hope someone can help with this problem I'm having.

I am building a shopping cart solution using the PayPal payflow api. I have been able to submit successful transactions but. I am having problems with AVS checks and validation.

It seems if I enter an incorrect expiry date the transaction is still successful. Entering a valid CVN number, the paypal response suggests `CVV2MATCH=N` even when the CVN number is correct.

I've been told I can set up fraud filters, but I cant seem to find these settings. I have checked paypal and the manager paypal accounts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response codes for AVS and CVV2 come from the card issuing bank, so if you're absolutely certain you're entering the correct value and it's still coming back with an N then you need to call the card issuing bank and as them why that would be happening.

Fraud Filters need to be activated on your account in order for you to have access to them.  The easiest way to do this is to call PayPal and request it.